# jqx - Grid sorting on address column not working

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I have used jqx grid for displaying customers data. But when i go for column sorting on address column it's not working. I think it's happen because address contains numeric value. here is code

```
var source = {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [
                { name: 'aa', type: 'string'},
                { name: 'bb', type: 'string'},
                { name: 'cc', type: 'string'}
            ],
            url: senddata,
            sortcolumn: 'create_date',
            sortdirection: 'desc'
        };



$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {columns: [
                { text: 'Address', datafield: 'aa', width: '30%' },
                { text: 'Total Units', datafield: 'bb', width: '10%' },
                { text: 'Extras', datafield: 'cc', width: '14%' }
            ],
            ready: function (){$('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid({ pagesizeoptions: page_opt});}
```

So i want it for first column (address) which contains numeric value at starting position in some of them. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of returning address as link(with anchor) from back-end it doesn't work. Because jqx grid considering whole  tag for sorting.

After creating custom link and only returning address as text from back-end, it works for me.